# need to read array content from text file in the below code by using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I need to read Admin, user etc from a text file. This code is for creating a folder structure and I want to read the folder names from text file.

```
@('Admin', 'user', 'server') | ForEach-Object {
    New-Item (Join-Path 'D:\test3\LV2\7212\win10\x64\' $_) -ItemType Directory -force
    }

@('ABC3D_X00-00','WXY3Z_X01-00') | ForEach-Object {
    New-Item (Join-Path 'D:\test3\LV2\7212\win10\x64\audio' $_) -ItemType Directory -force
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you could expand your question a bit more? At the moment you're not telling us what you have already tried. Also it is generally a good habit to make the question clear without having to refer to the title, even if that means a bit of repetition, as it does help people understand more quickly what you are after.

Comment: The code which you have posted and the question which you are asking are totally irrelevant. You need [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6) in order to read from text files. I would suggest you rephrase your question so that it conveys some extra information.

Comment: Hi vivek, i just tried  Get-Content  and  some modification now its working thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have a file named "stuff.txt". The file contains the following:

```
Admin
user
server
```

In the same directory as "stuff.txt", you have a script named "make.ps1", which contains:

```
Param($ParentDirectory)
$folder_names = $(gc -Path .\stuff.txt)
foreach ($folder_name in $folder_names ) {
    New-Item -Path $ParentDirectory -Name $folder_name -ItemType Folder
}
```

You then call the script passing in the parent directory:

```
C:\> make.ps1 -ParentDirectory '...'
```

If you don't want to do this as a script, just make the $ParentDirectory name a regular old variable and assign it the starting directory's path.